# Git workflow feature branch needs another branch

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I have a master branch that needs two features added and both features need to be discussed via Pull Requests, but I have a problem I finished branch `feature_1` and filled a Pull Request to the master branch. I need to start `feature_2` and I noticed that it needs some of the changes I made in `feature_1`. What is the normal way to tackle this situation within the Git workflow? if it was my repository I would just merge the feature to master and create a new branch from there for the other feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need `feature_1` + `master`? 
Then simply branch `feature_2` from `feature_1` and not from `master`.

The *normal* way of handling such a situation is not having it in the first place: Either `feature_1` and `feature_2` are independent of each other, then they can be developed in parallel. Or there are dependencies, then they need to be developed one after the other.

Comment: Then feature_2 -> master would be the actual Pull Request instead of both? isn't it better to just build upon feature_1 without branching it?

Comment: That's what Thomas is saying. If the two features aren't actually independent, then they either need to be developed in sequence or as a single feature, depending on the situation. Sounds like your features are not isolated enough to be parallel branches.